# Popup on every list item when clicked, with a function to write less code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

im trying to make a list of users  and when i click any item i want a popup

with the option to DELETE IT or CANCEL,

This is what i got so far for **EVERY ITEM**

```
echo "<li><a href=#popupid7' data-rel='popup'><img src='user.png' class='ui-li-icon'>
                <p><strong>PEREZ, CARLOS </strong></p>
                <p class='ui-li-aside'><strong>$y - 01/10/2014</strong>PM</p>
       </a></li>";
```

plus the popup code:

```
<div data-role='popup' id='popupid7' data-theme='a' class='ui-corner-all'> 
    <form> 
        <div style='padding:10px 20px;'> 
            <h3>Please sign in</h3> 
            <label for='un' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Username:</label> 
            <input type='text' name='user' id='un' value='' placeholder='username' data-theme='a'> 
            <label for='pw' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Password:</label> 
            <input type='password' name='pass' id='pw' value='' placeholder='password' data-theme='a'> 
            <button type='submit' class='ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check'>Sign in</button> 
        </div> 
    </form> 
</div>
```

i want to make it **SHORTER with a function,**
 this is where i need your guide/help.

because i try to do it via JS but im not sure if this is good:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#listusers li").click(function(){
        var popid=$(this).attr("id");
        displayPopupid(popid)
    });
});

Function displayPopupid(numberid){
    document.getElementById("emptydiv").innerHTML=" \
<a href='# " + numberid + "' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' class='ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a' data-transition='pop'>Sign in</a> \
<div data-role='popup' id='adC' data-theme='a' class='ui-corner-all'> \
    <form> \
        <div style='padding:10px 20px;'> \
            <h3>Please sign in</h3> \
            <label for='un' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Username:</label> \
            <input type='text' name='user' id='un' value='' placeholder='username' data-theme='a'> \
            <label for='pw' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Password:</label> \
            <input type='password' name='pass' id='pw' value='' placeholder='password' data-theme='a'> \
            <button type='submit' class='ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check'>Sign in</button> \
        </div> \
    </form> \
</div>";
}
</script>
```

So.. i want to know the best way to do it,
JS, JQ, or AJAX.

*i have to mention that when i click the DELETE USER button it should be a form in php to delete it and know the id of the user that i clicked*

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I FORGOT: i tryed to add the function of clicking it but, it mess up if i use the code inside a DIV with document.getElementById("emptydiv").innerHTML=" popupcode"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one common popup div. Here is how you can achieve.

Add onclick handler with userId as a param to identify user for every item

```
  <li>
      <a onclick="openPopUp(userId)" data-rel='popup'> whatever.. </a>
  </li>
```

Common Popup Code

```
<div data-role='popup' id='myPopupDiv' data-theme='a' class='ui-corner-all'> 
        <input type="hidden" id="userId"/>....other fields pwd/name etc
```

Click handler

```
function openPopUp(userId){
  $("#userId").val(userId);
  $("#myPopupDiv").popup("open");
}
```

Comment: yeah that sounds fine the question is inside the Common popup code, how could i get the userId, so i can post it. I can get it in the function but i can't get it at the common popup, can i?

Comment: nevermind, just found the #userId as hidden... thats probably a good idea, is there any other way to not use a hidden input field to carry over the userId value?

Comment: You can declare global variable and set it to the userId inside openPopup handler.